# Swipe gesture recognizer in Xamarin Forms for windows phone (8.1 & 10) platform

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-runtime

How to best implement a swipe [gesture recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/) in Xamarin Forms for windows phone (8.1 & 10) platform?

I see a lot of examples for [renderers](http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/) that do that for Android and iOS platform. But not for WinRT or UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see a lot of examples for renderers that do that for Android and iOS platform. But not for WinRT or UWP.

Currently, there is no such "SwipeGestureRecognizer" api for Xamarin.Forms. But you could custom `SwipeGestureRecognizer` base on [`PanGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/pan/). I have written the following code for simulating "SwipeGestureRecognizer". But the threshold I used is just for testing and not the real one, you can modify the threshold based on your requirement.

```
public enum SwipeDeriction
{
    Left = 0,
    Rigth,
    Above,
    Bottom
}

public class SwipeGestureReconginzer : PanGestureRecognizer
{
    public delegate void SwipeRequedt(object sender, SwipeDerrictionEventArgs e);

    public event EventHandler<SwipeDerrictionEventArgs> Swiped;

    public SwipeGestureReconginzer()
    {
        this.PanUpdated += SwipeGestureReconginzer_PanUpdated;
    }

    private void SwipeGestureReconginzer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TotalY > -5 | e.TotalY < 5)
        {
            if (e.TotalX > 10)
            {
                Swiped(this, new SwipeDerrictionEventArgs(SwipeDeriction.Rigth));
            }
            if (e.TotalX < -10)
            {
                Swiped(this, new SwipeDerrictionEventArgs(SwipeDeriction.Left));
            }
        }

        if (e.TotalX > -5 | e.TotalX < 5)
        {
            if (e.TotalY > 10)
            {
                Swiped(this, new SwipeDerrictionEventArgs(SwipeDeriction.Bottom));
            }
            if (e.TotalY < -10)
            {
                Swiped(this, new SwipeDerrictionEventArgs(SwipeDeriction.Above));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SwipeDerrictionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SwipeDeriction Deriction { get; }

    public SwipeDerrictionEventArgs(SwipeDeriction deriction)
    {
        Deriction = deriction;
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
  var swipe = new SwipeGestureReconginzer();
  swipe.Swiped += Tee_Swiped;
  TestLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(swipe);

  private void Tee_Swiped(object sender, SwipeDerrictionEventArgs e)
  {
      switch (e.Deriction)
      {
          case SwipeDeriction.Above:
              {
              }
              break;

          case SwipeDeriction.Left:
              {
              }
              break;

          case SwipeDeriction.Rigth:
              {
              }
              break;

          case SwipeDeriction.Bottom:
              {
              }
              break;

          default:
              break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: I haven't been able to test this approach yet - but I really like it. I just might be able to add swipe gesture support to most of the UI controls without having to write platform renderers for them.

Comment: The only caveat I can see is the ability to detect and fire event only when the swipe is completed - but with a slight tweaking around threshold and a timer, I think I will be able to manage it. Thanks :)